# Delete object from array in mongodb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have simple application on rails with Mongodb(Mondoid mapper). Scaffold `posts`, and I trying to implement rating functional. `Post` has next structure:

```
> class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :title, type: String
  field :description, type: String
  field :rank, type: Integer, default: "0"
  field :voter_up, type: Array, default: []
  field :voter_down, type: Array, default: []
```

As you can see there are two field `voter_up`, `_down`. It's to add users, depending on how they voted. `self.voter_up << user.id`, or `self.voter_down << user.id`. In database it looks like:

```
"voter_up" : [
    ObjectId("4ee08b6e405f3d0a29000005"),
    ObjectId("4ee0aaff405f3d0a2900003a")
]
```

And if user changed his mind and wants to vote contrary. For example in first time user voted UP. And then voted DOWN. In this situation I need to delete this user from array `voter_up` and add to `voter_down`. From rails console it works `array.delete(object)`, but if I try that `self.voter_up.delete(user.id)` in model function - nothing happens. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that both of your console and modal would work. Because the delete here you are using is a ruby array method not the mongoids. So You need to call save after delete to push the changed array to server.

```
     self.voter_up.delete(user.id)
     self.save
```

Answer (score 0):

self.voter_up << "#{user.id}", or self.voter_down << "#{user.id}"
I think this will work, have a try